# In Python, are strings considered as lists?

Tags: python

I am just curious whether strings are considered as lists.

Comment: 'string' is not list but `string` is iterable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In almost all languages Strings are indeed lists of characters, so yes, in that sense Strings are lists. However, strings are their own entities. They have their own methods, and not all list methods can be used on strings. However, there is an overlap. You can slice, iterate and concatenate strings as if they were lists, and even use a few list methods (ie. `len` and `index`). However, the biggest difference is that **Strings in Python are not mutable**. With a list you can do `my_list[5] = "a"`. If you try this with a String, you'll receive a `TypeError`.

**EDIT:**

As is mentioned in the comment of another answer, immutability may not be the **biggest** difference (that's a matter of opinion), but something I don't see mentioned anywhere else is the fact that lists can be multidimensional. While you can easily have a two, three or even four dimensional list, something like that is not possible with strings (though arguably `my_list = ["foo", "bar"]` could be looked at as multidimensional since you can call `my_list[1][2]`, it is not solely a String, it's a combination of Strings and lists). I would be thoroughly impressed if someone could produce a "String Of Strings" like you can a "List Of Lists."

Answer (score 5):

Strings and lists are both sequences, so `for` loops can iterate over them, but they are definitely two different types.

```
for c in 'abcd':
    print c

for i in [1,2,3,4]:
    print i
```

Comment: Thank you for the useful answer. http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange

Answer (score 4):

Strings are lists like a cat is a marshmallow.  They're similar in a lot of ways - you can pet them, they're both soft, they can be real sweet to you, and they can make a mess on your floor.

And you can eat a marshmallow, but if you try to eat a cat, it will throw a big sharp, bloody error in your face.

So it is with strings and lists.  You can do many of the same things to them, because they are both sequences, but some things you should only do with strings, and some things only with lists.

Comment: +1 for being the only person to really say __hell not, they aren't__. They are sequence of something, great, but what else? I see people saying _hashable_, or _the biggest difference_. IMHO we cannot talk about _the biggest difference_ but the _biggest similarity_. They are two different things which happen to contain  a sequence of something, but that something is far from being similar.

Comment: In retrospect, I should have gone with a duck, in deference to duck typing.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what others have said. Strings are not mutable and hashable: you cannot change strings in place and they can be keys in dictionaries, and members of sets. Lists are mutable and not hashable, you can change a list in place, but they cannot be keys in a dictionary or members of sets.

```
# Hashability
>>> {['a', 'b'] : 1}  # With lists: fails    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>> {'ab' : 1}        # With strings: works 
{'ab': 1}
```